# counting visible divs with class name jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble using the `:visible` with class name.

Example:

```
<div class="groupedDiv" id="group1">
    <div class="level1">
        Apples
        <div class="level2"> || L2-apple </div>
    </div>

    <div class="level1" style="display:none;">
        Oranges 
        <div class="level2"> || [L2-orange] </div>
    </div>
</div>

<br/>

<div class="groupedDiv" id="group1">
    <div class="level1">
        Roses
        <div class="level2"> || L2-rose </div>
        <div class="level3"> l3 rose </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I want to count the # of visible divs of class `level1`

`$(".level1 :visible").length;` gives me output 3, doesn't this supposed to output 2 ?

`$(".level1 :visible").parent().length;` gives me output 2 which is correct.

I have created this example at http://jsfiddle.net/metalhawk/P87jS/

Any suggestions are helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`$(".level1 :visible")` is a descendant selector: you are selecting all visible elements that are descendants of `.level1`.  There are three `div` elements that are visible beneath `.level1` elements.

Use this instead:

```
$(".level1:visible").length;
```

[See your fiddle per my update](http://jsfiddle.net/P87jS/5/).

Comment: @lonesomeday, Any way for this to update while divs hide/show on the page? Like live? It works great on page load but for a sort/search where divs are removed, any way to get this changing?

Comment: @JamisonHill Whenever you run it, it will give the current number. You'd need to run the selector again after every change. There may be more elegant ways to do this, but it's hard to say without looking in depth at your code.

Comment: @lonesomeday - Here's a jFiddle with my code. Very simple but is not updating with search: http://jsfiddle.net/KYjfk/10/ Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 5):

Pretty sure you need to do `$(".level1:visible").length;`

the Space is breaking the code